# Click even not triggering even though I'm using "on"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
  if(amStatus === "Logout") {
    $('#row-qfauto-1 .large-9').append('<a id="next-password" class="button button-next" href="javascript:;">Next</a>')
    $('#next-password').click(function() {
      $('#row-html2-0').addClass('next-visible')
      $(window).resize()
    })
  }

  $('.button-next').on('click', function() {
    $(this).hide()
    $(window).resize()
  })
```

As you can see `button-next` is being added dynamically with jQuery. So in order to make the button disappear when clicked I decided to use `on`.

However, the button doesn't disappear. It just stays there. When I do

```
  $('.button-next').click(function() {
    $(this).hide()
    $(window).resize()   
  })
```

twice in the console, then the button disappears. Weird. What could be the problem?

Live site: http://www.chineselearnonline.com/amember/signup/cloprogressive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (amStatus === "Logout") {
  $('#row-qfauto-1 .large-9').append('<a id="next-password" class="button button-next" href="javascript:;">Next</a>')
  $('#next-password').click(function() {
    $('#row-html2-0').addClass('next-visible')
    $(window).resize()
  })
}

$('#row-qfauto-1 .large-9').on('click', '.button-next', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).hide()
  $(window).resize()
});
```

> Note: You are assigning event listener to `#next-password` as well as `.button-next`, is this the way you want to implement ?
>
> Also make sure you dont have redundant `id` in your `DOM`

Answer (score 0):

Try event delegation

```
$(document).on("click", ".button-next", function() {
  // do stuff
})
```

or attaching click event when element created using `jQuery()`

```
   $("#row-qfauto-1 .large-9")
   .append($("<a></a>", {
       "id":"next-password",
       "class":"button button-next",
       "href":"javascript:;"
       "on": {
            "click": function() {
                       $(this).hide()
                       $(window).resize()
                     }
       },
       "html":"Next"  
    }))
```